# How to fetch data from table as per user input date with formatting using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need one solution. I need to fetch data from table as per `date` using PHP and MySQL but here the user input is `string` type. I am explaining my table below.

```
id        name             date

 1         aaa         2017-10-23 16:56:34

 2         bbb         2017-10-23 16:56:34

 3         ccc         2017-10-12 13:56:34

 4         ddd         2017-10-23 16:56:34
```

Here My `date` column datatype is `datetime` and my user input is string like `2017-10-23`. Here I need query to fetch data from table after formatting the user input date.

Comment: there is no problem using that user input string, mysql will understand that format too, just make your attempt in the selection of data

Comment: No directly its not working.

Comment: nope, if its datetime it should work just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8218df/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql's [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to compare only the date and not the time.

eg.:
`select * from table where date(date) = '2017-10-23'`